# Kubeflow forbidden: User system:serviceaccount:kubeflow-user-example-com:default-editor cannot create resource inferenceservices in API group

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to execute below commands in a Kubeflow(v1.4.1) Jupyter Notebook.

```
KServe = KServeClient()
KServe.create(isvc)
```

I am getting mentioned error while attempting to execute above mentioned command.

```
ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '86bb1b59-20ae-4127-9732-d0355671b12f', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'a5a5d542-8a9a-4031-90d9-4faf01914391', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '6846984d-14c5-4f4d-9251-fe97d91b17fc', 'Date': 'Thu, 02 Jun 2022 07:53:30 GMT', 'Content-Length': '429'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"inferenceservices.serving.kserve.io is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:kubeflow-user-example-com:default-editor\" cannot create resource \"inferenceservices\" in API group \"serving.kserve.io\" in the namespace \"kubeflow-user-example-com\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"group":"serving.kserve.io","kind":"inferenceservices"},"code":403}
```

As a mitigation step I have added underlying manifests to my Kubernetes cluster via kubectl apply -f <manifest-location.yaml>

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: sla-manager-service-role
  namespace: default   //(have tried it with kubeflow-user-example-com as well)
  labels:
    app: sla-manager-app
rules:
- apiGroups: ["serving.kserve.io"] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["inferenceservices"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: sla-manager-service-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default   //(have added it with default-editor as well)
  namespace: kubeflow-user-example-com
```

But this does not resolved the issue.

Output I am receiving for

```
kubectl auth can-i create inferenceservice --as=system:serviceaccount:kubeflow-user-example-com:default-editor -n default

(Output) no
```

```
kubectl auth can-i create inferenceservices

(Output) yes
```

Can you please help me with what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to know that KServe is not comaptible with Kubeflow version 1.4 and works for Kubeflow version >=1.5.

Switching to kfserving 0.6 resolved my issue.